# How to modify an item's key/data with cursor when using LMDB?

Tags: c++, lmdb

I want to know in LMDB how to modify an item's key or data with cursor?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have seen some documentation, but still don't know how to do this assignment..

Comment: provide the code u have tried.. so that we can do modifications